# Web Progress Bar in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, c#-2.0

I'm looking for a way to display a "progress bar" in web using webforms with c#.

I made a quick example, I just want a label to show like 1%, 2%, 3% etc.. about a background process that will be running in the server. And when it finish update something like showing an alert or something, The real need is a little more complicated than that but getting the bases I think I can make it by my own. The problem that I having with the code is that I'm always getting 0.. in my "progress bar" it doesn't get updated, I'm missing something but I don't know what it is.

**Edit**

I tried to alert the value every second to see the value instead of the label, but it is not working anyway.

I missed the `OnClientClick="javascript:GetProgress();"` in the first queston, i Updated it, it is not working anyway

**Edit 2**

HttpConext.Current is being null when calling it as a thread.. Should I use something more than a session or application, perhaps a singletone class?

Any Help would be really appreciated.

---

**Importanth thigs from The ASPX and JS**

```
 <div style="width: 800px" class="css_container">
        <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
            EnableScriptLocalization="true" AsyncPostBackTimeout="60000" EnablePageMethods="true">
        </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanel" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server"  Text="Do Something"
                                    CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btn_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:GetProgress();" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </div>
```

---

```
  function GetProgress() {
       PageMethods.GetProcessed(function(result) {
                alert(result);
                if (result < 100) {
                    setTimeout(function(){GetProgress();}, 1000);
                }                  
            });

    }
```

---

**Important Things from Code Behind**

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true), ScriptMethod]
    public  static string GetProcessed()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["processed"].ToString();
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
             Session["processed"] = 0;
        }
    }

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       AClass oClass = new AClass();
        Thread oThread = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                oClass.UpdateSession();
            });
           oThread.Start();
    }
```

---

**Important Things from the Aclass**

```
public class AClass
{ 
    public void UpdateSession()
    {
          for(int i = 0; i< 100; i++)
          {

            HttpContext.Current.Session["processed"] =  i;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be because this line `//document.getElementById("divProgress").innerHTML = result + "%";` is commented out?

Comment: i tried to alert it, instead of the label.. i didnt post the label for no confusing i will remove it from the question sorry

Comment: You are accessing the Session object from a background thread... in ASP.NET that's bad practice.

Comment: how it would be a good practice?, there is any recommendation of how to archieve the thing that i want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the Idea of @Mike.. and altered it a bit because the HttpContext.Current is null... and replaced it with an static object. this worked good for me also made some concurrency test and worked fine ..

```
<div style="width: 800px" class="css_container">
        <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
            EnableScriptLocalization="true" AsyncPostBackTimeout="60000" EnablePageMethods="true">
        </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanel" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:HiddenField ID="correlationKey" runat="server" />
               <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server"  Text="Do Something"
                                    CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btn_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:GetProgress();" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </div>
```

---

```
function GetProgress() {
    PageMethods.GetProcessed(document.getElementById("correlationKey").value,
        function(result) {
            alert(result);
            if (result < 100) {
                setTimeout(function(){GetProgress();}, 1000);
            }   
        });   
}
```

---

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // NEW CODE
    // set the hidden field value here with a correlation key
    var correlationKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    this.correlationKey.Value = correlationKey;

    AClass oClass = new AClass(); 
    Thread oThread = new Thread(delegate() 
        { 
            oClass.UpdateSession(correlationKey); 
        }); 
    oThread.Start(); 
}
```

---

```
public class AClass
{
    public static Dictionary<string, int> ProcessedQueue { get; set; }

    public void UpdateSession(string correlationKey)
    {
        var dictionary = ProcessedQueue; // HttpContext.Current.Application["ProcessedQueue"] as Dictionary<string, int>;
        if (dictionary == null)
        {
           dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
           ProcessedQueue = dictionary;// HttpContext.Current.Application["ProcessedQueue"] = dictionary;
        }

        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(correlationKey)) { dictionary.Add(correlationKey, 0); }

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
             dictionary[correlationKey] = i;
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true), ScriptMethod]
public static string GetProcessed(string correlationKey)
{
     var dictionary = AClass.ProcessedQueue; //     HttpContext.Current.Application["ProcessedQueue"] as Dictionary<string, int>;
     if (dictionary == null || !dictionary.ContainsKey(correlationKey)) { return "0"; }
     return dictionary[correlationKey].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there might be a few things going on here:

1. Your thread might be terminating at the end of the response. I think you can fix that by changing the way you define your thread:

   ```
   Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(oClass.UpdateSession));
   oThread.IsBackground = true; // Set this
   oThread.Start();
   ```
2. You're returning a string percent to your callback function, and then comparing it against a number. It's not really an issue, but for the sake of good programming, you should change your server-side `GetProcessed()` to return an actual integer:

   ```
   public static int GetProcessed()
   {
       int result = 0;
       int.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.Session["processed"].ToString()), out result);
       return result;
   }
   ```
3. UpdatePanel requests initiate a full page lifecycle behind the scenes. Can you verify that this code isn't resetting your progress every tick of your GetProcessed() web method?

   ```
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
        Session["processed"] = 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Ah yeah, I bet the `UpdatePanel` is still doing is horrible magic, even though he's using javascript to get hit the server.  I wonder if #3 is the thing to check.

Comment: Maybe using this in a ViewState instead of a session for concurrency issues?

Comment: You know, i think when is a Thread, session is lost.. HttpContext.Current <- NUllException

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are calling in on a different `Session` than the one the value is being updated on. So, you have a couple of options.

First you could make that an `Application` variable if your application is only used by one user (very unlikely but I don't know anything about the app).

Second, you can use some sort of correlation key so that you can get the value from an `Application` variable that is keyed.

Make a change in the button click:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // NEW CODE
    // set the hidden field value here with a correlation key
    var correlationKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    this.correlationKey.Value = correlationKey;

    AClass oClass = new AClass(); 
    Thread oThread = new Thread(delegate() 
        { 
            oClass.UpdateSession(correlationKey); 
        }); 
    oThread.Start(); 
}
```

Now modify the JavaScript like this:

```
function GetProgress() {
    PageMethods.GetProcessed(document.getElementById("correlationKey").value,
        function(result) {
            alert(result);
            if (result < 100) {
                setTimeout(function(){GetProgress();}, 1000);
            }   
        });   
}
```

Now modify the `GetProcessed` method like this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true), ScriptMethod]
public  static string GetProcessed(string correlationKey)
{
    var dictionary = Application["ProcessedQueue"] as Dictionary<string, int>;
    if (dictionary == null || !dictionary.ContainsKey(correlationKey)) { return "0"; }
    return dictionary[correlationKey].ToString();
}
```

Now modify the `UpdateSession` method like this:

```
public void UpdateSession(string correlationKey)
{
    var dictionary = Application["ProcessedQueue"] as Dictionary<string, int>;
    if (dictionary == null)
    {
        dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        Application["ProcessedQueue"] = dictionary;
    }

    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(correlationKey)) { dictionary.Add(correlationKey, 0); }

    for (int i = 0; i< 100; i++)
    {
        dictionary[correlationKey] =  i;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

And now clean out the `Page_Load`.

Comment: I think I'm missing the session with the Thread.. HttpContext.Current is NUll.. I can't Access Application just like that neither from the WebMethod because is static nor the AClass.. should I use something different I have to use the HttpContext.Current I think

Comment: Yeah, build your own static `SessionState` class -- I've had to do that before.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I missed something, but your javascript (at least what you put in the question), isn't updating anything on the page.  You said you have 0 in the progress bar all the time, which could be because you commented out the line that changes the display.

`//document.getElementById("divProgress").innerHTML = result + "%";`

Is the `alert` showing the correct value?  Also, have you confirmed that `UpdateSession()` is running correctly and actually setting a value in the session?

Comment: Can you verify `UpdateSession()` is running?

Comment: Also, is your `GetProgress()` in your javascript running off the timer as it should be since the value is < 100?  I'm assuming that you're getting an alert every second with 0 in it?

Comment: right, the alert shows itself every second with the value of 0